# Lint check "RemoveWorkManagerInitializer" fails, how to fix that?

Tags: android, lint, android-workmanager

My App class implements Configuration.Provider.getWorkManagerConfiguration, and regarding this article: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#on-demand

I switched default initializer with this string in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

The code works as I need - no default initializer calls, but the only Configuration.Provider.getWorkManagerConfiguration.

If I run lint check I still see the error: Remove androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer when using on-deman initialization.

---

- Android studio 4.1 beta 5
- Gradle plugin: 4.1.0-beta05
- Work manager:  2.3.4

Any thoughts on how to deal with it?

Comment: Sounds like you should [file an issue against WorkManager](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906) with a sample project that shows the Lint check not working.

Comment: I have the same problem. Please, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I have reported it to the google issue tracker, but no answer yet, for me if I remember correctly I've just removed this lint check rule.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to remove the default initializer**. To provide your own configuration, you must first remove the default initializer. To do so, update `AndroidManifest.xml` using the merge rule `tools:node="remove"`.

Since WorkManager 2.6, App Startup is used internally within WorkManager. To provide a custom initializer you need to remove the `androidx.startup` node.

If you don't use App Startup in your app, you can remove it completely.

```
<!-- If you want to disable android.startup completely. -->
 <provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    tools:node="remove">
 </provider>
```

Otherwise, remove only the WorkManagerInitializer node.

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="merge">
    <!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
 </provider>
```

While using an version of WorkManager older than 2.6, remove workmanager-init instead:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/configuration/custom-configuration#on-demand